# Finding libraries for GRASS Installation Linux

Tags: grass-gis, linux, amazon-web-services

I am installing GRASS on Linux. I have gotten as far as running `Make` in these instructions: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/binary/linux/snapshot/INSTALL

I get this for multiple libraries:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libproj.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have found this file in the /usr/lib64 folder, so have added that folder to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH. But it still fails to find the files. I am new to Linux. Is there something else I should be doing?  I am using Amazon linux if that makes any difference

Comment: Errors like these often indicate that you are missing a development library. In this case libproj-devel. Since Amazon uses an `rpm` based package manager, you might try `yum install libproj-devel` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I found this file in /usr/local/lib/ and added that to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env. variable. It was not in the folder /usr/lib64/ along with other .so files.

This allowed me to install GRASS with no errors